# xpath/selenium - chaining contains and position functions

Tags: selenium, xpath

Basically I want to take the 2nd element from `//*[contains(@class, 'text-1')]`

`//*[contains(@class, 'text-1')][2]` doesn't work (returns an empty set) while `//*[contains(@class, 'text-1')][1]` returns the entire set.

I found a partial solution of enclosing in parentheses - `(//*[contains(@class, 'text-1')])[2]`. While this works, I can't chain several of these together, e.g.

`(//*[contains(@class, 'text-1')])[2](//*[contains(@class, 'text-2')])[5](//*[contains(@class, 'text-1')])[3]` - that gives an incorrect syntax error.

Anyone could help with this one please?

Comment: By Chaining are you looking at using an logical condition between each of the xpath?

Comment: Basically I want it to take the second element out of the elements that contains the "text-1" class, then from the elements inside it take the 5th element that contains the "text-2" class and so on.

Comment: It is better to see the html

Comment: Here's a simplified example - https://pastebin.com/5Wr4z8mp
I need the path to "Sentence48", note that the placeholder tags can be anything and may be more than one nesting level.
Thank you.

Comment: So what exactly distinguishes your target `Sentence48` from all other sentences? Is it the text of the sentence, it's location within its parent's child nodes, something else?

Comment: The text (in all places) can change. I need to extract the text from that node.

Comment: But what is "that node"? Is it always the 48th node? What is special about it that makes it the target? That's the only way we can solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer -
`//descendant::*[contains(@class, 'text-1')][2]//descendant::*[contains(@class, 'text-2')])[5]//descendant::*[contains(@class, 'text-1')])[3]`

Comment: Your XPath doesn't work. Fix it with : `//*[contains(@class, 'text-1')][2]/descendant::*[contains(@class, 'text-2')][5]/descendant::*[contains(@class, 'text-1')][3]` or alternatively just use : `//*[contains(@class, 'text-1')][2]//*[contains(@class,'text-2')][5]//*[*[contains(@class,'text-1')]][3]/*`

Comment: Hmm, //descendant worked for me in tests, but I'll try.